# How can the executable name of a program listed in a Dash search be determined?

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, executable

Searching on the dash, I can see the program listed as "Personal File Sharing". How can I find the executable name of this program such that it can be launched in a terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and use `grep` to search for "personal file sharing" in `/usr/share/applications` folder.

In fact, you will have this output:

```
$ grep -R -i "personal file sharing" /usr/share/applications
/usr/share/applications/gnome-user-share-properties.desktop:Name=Personal File Sharing
```

Now, if we do this:

```
$ grep "Exec" /usr/share/applications/gnome-user-share-properties.desktop
Exec=gnome-file-share-properties
```

That the actual program that runs is `gnome-file-share-properties, which is located at

```
$ which gnome-file-share-properties
/usr/bin/gnome-file-share-properties
```

To be more specific, what happens is that in linux there are `.desktop` files. They are somewhat similar to Windows' shortcuts. These files contain 
fields `Name=` and `Exec=`. Name part is how the program shows up in the dash search and unity panel. Exec is the actual binary that gets executed

Comment: If my answer was helpful , please upvote. If I solved your problem, please click gray checkmark to accept the answer as a valid solution

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. How to search for the launcher in `/usr/share/applications` was particularly helpful.